# using cin.clear() to remove the fail state in an exception

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to understand why cin.clear is getting rid of the first word instead of the second if
a first and last name are entered, and a number for age. for instance, if the input is:

```
    Lee 18
    Lua 21
    Mary Beth 19
    Stu 33
    -1
```

then shouldn't the "Beth" in "Mary Beth 19" be skipped? Why is it clearing "Mary" instead?

Output:

```
    Lee 18
    Lua 21
    Beth 19
    Stu 33
```

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   string inputName;
   int age;
   // Set exception mask for cin stream
   cin.exceptions(ios::failbit);

   while(inputName != "-1") {
      // FIXME: The following line will throw an ios_base::failure.
      //        Insert a try/catch statement to catch the exception.
      //        Clear cin's failbit to put cin in a useable state.
      cin >> inputName;
      try {
         cin >> age;
         cout << inputName << " " << (age + 1) << endl;    
      }catch(exception ex) {
         cin.clear();
      }
   }
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin.clear()` doesn't remove anything from the input stream. It resets the error flags. [Look it up](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the input line

```
Mary Beth 19
```

the first

```
cin >> inputName;
```

will read `Mary` into `inputName`.

Then

```
cin >> age;
```

attempts to parse `Beth` as an integer, but it will fail and thrown an exception. However, and here's the important part: The input isn't discarded! Instead the input read pointer is unmodified, it will still be "pointing" to `Beth`.

You clear the error and the loop continues as normal, coming back to

```
cin >> inputName;
```

which will then continue reading the `Beth` into `inputName`, loosing the old value `Mary`.

Comment: Oh interesting, I guess I was thinking it would clear what was currently being attempted, not the most recent placement into a variable. Is there another function that would be better than cin.clear(), or is it just a logic puzzle and I have things out of order?

Comment: @T_lastname To begin with I suggest you use e.g. `std::getline` to read line by line into a string. Put that string into an `std::istringstream` and extract the data from that. If extraction of the integer fail (don't need exceptions for that, just a plain `if (!(stream >> age))`) then clear the error, extract the next "word" into a dummy variable, and try to read the `age` again.